# Как получить данные текущего пользователя в DetailView?

Tags: django

Пытаюсь получить данные текущего пользователя для вывода на страницу. По ссылке, указанной мною http://127.0.0.1:8000/cabinet/1, выдается ошибка. Почему?

models.py (crm)

```
rom django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

urls.py (третья строка в паттерне)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from crm.views import PersonalAccount, index, Registr
from orders.views import admin_order_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/orders/order/<order_id>/change/', admin_order_detail, name='admin_order_detail'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cabinet/<pk>', PersonalAccount.as_view(), name='pers_account'),
    path('registr/', Registr.as_view(), name='registr'),
    path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('accounts/login/', login, name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', logout, name='logout'),
    path('product/', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('coupons/', include('coupons.urls', namespace='coupon')),
    path('', index, name='index'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py (crm)

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render
from shop.models import Product
from crm.models import CustomUser

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
#    slider_list = CmsSlider.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    dict_obj = {'products': products}
    return render(request, './index.html', dict_obj)

class PersonalAccount(DetailView):
    model = CustomUser 
    template_name = 'pers_account.html'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую ошибку вы получаете? добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не передали аргументы или передали их неправильно при построении ссылки(это либо id,pk,slug)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/586151)

Comment: эм,что?Это является ответом. Я сказал,что не передали аргументы..

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, с чем это связано. Заменил в шаблоне входной аргумент на user.id (раньше был CustomUser.pk, но адрес 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cabinet/1' появлялся). Теперь все работает.